# Magento 2: Where are the Token-based authentication access token stored?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, access, token

I have been following along with this guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

This guide shows how a token can be requested and shows how a token can be used in a request. However, it does not show how a token can be revoked or removed. Do you guys know where the tokens are stored and how we can view/revoke them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The customer token is stored in the table `oauth_token`. A typical entry looks like this:

```
   entity_id: 1
 consumer_id: NULL
    admin_id: NULL
 customer_id: 2
        type: access
       token: 5mv91ux3shp0fz1wpt4p93gu28m1aj7b
      secret: 7s9x3al8grs9tf9ug80m3dc8wkngbo8l
    verifier: NULL
callback_url:
     revoked: 0
  authorized: 0
   user_type: 3
  created_at: 2021-05-20 12:59:32
```

The `created_at` field determines whether the token is valid or not. Token will be valid up to the configuration setting you have set at `oauth/access_token_lifetime/customer`. This option you can find at `Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Customer Token Lifetime (hours)`